Comic in which Wonder Woman tunnels through the ground by spinning really fast
Sometime in the last ten years, I saw an excerpt of a comic in which Wonder Woman was trapped underground, I believe with one other person. To resolve this conundrum, she turned sideways and spun so quickly that her body functioned as a drill.
My memory is of a cross-sectional view of an dirt tunnel, with a dead end on the right side of the panel. Wonder Woman turned so that her body was parallel to the ground and she was floating in mid air with her arms still at her sides. Then she just used her entire body as a drill, head first into the dead end. There was some dialogue but I think it more or less amounted to describing the situation out loud.
I only saw an image of these 3-4 panels, probably in a Reddit or Tumblr post, so it's possible that this is a fan comic. The reason I suspect it might not be a page from a published comic is that I recall Wonder Woman having the hairstyle of her earliest comics appearances, but the idea of super-spinning made me think that the comic post-dates the Lynda Carter TV series. Of course, I could be misremembering her appearance or unaware of a long comics tradition of spinning-based crisis resolution.
What is the source of this comic? My best attempts at constructing a search query have yielded nothing but gifs of the 70s TV show.

Superman and Supergirl do this a lot. https://i.sstatic.net/ArUWS.png
